# Data expansion so to create all possible combinations of two covariates

Tags: stata, expand

My dataset looks like the following:

```
clear all

input id year x
      1  1992 1
      1  1995 5
      1  1996 7
      2  1992 2
      2  1993 4
end
```

I need to expand the dataset according to the `id`-specific number of observations and create the following data structure then used for further computations (basically, for each `id`-`year` combination of values I have to repeat the initial set of `year` values):

```
     id  year  y2   x 
      1  1992  1992 1
      1  1992  1995 1
      1  1992  1996 1
      1  1995  1992 5
      1  1995  1995 5
      1  1995  1996 5
      1  1996  1992 7
      1  1996  1995 7
      1  1996  1996 7
      2  1992  1992 2
      2  1992  1993 2
      2  1993  1992 4
      2  1993  1993 4
```

The expansion is easily obtained with:

```
bysort id: gen N = _N
expand n_obs, gen(expanded)
```

However, perhaps the problem is trivial, but I cannot find a suitable strategy to obtain `y2`. Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some technique; `joinby` is the key. Since you subsequently edited your question to include the variable x, I edited this reply to retain only id and y2 in the file being joined to the original.

```
// setup test data
clear all
input id year x
      1  1992 1
      1  1995 5
      1  1996 7
      2  1992 2
      2  1993 4
end
tempfile t1
save `t1'
clear

// do the job
use `t1'
rename year y2
keep id y2
joinby id using `t1'
order id year y2
sort id year y2
list, sepby(id)
```

Which gives us

```
     +----------------------+
     | id   year     y2   x |
     |----------------------|
  1. |  1   1992   1992   1 |
  2. |  1   1992   1995   1 |
  3. |  1   1992   1996   1 |
  4. |  1   1995   1992   5 |
  5. |  1   1995   1995   5 |
  6. |  1   1995   1996   5 |
  7. |  1   1996   1992   7 |
  8. |  1   1996   1995   7 |
  9. |  1   1996   1996   7 |
     |----------------------|
 10. |  2   1992   1992   2 |
 11. |  2   1992   1993   2 |
 12. |  2   1993   1992   4 |
 13. |  2   1993   1993   4 |
     +----------------------+
```

Comment: For the sake of completeness, I think you have to do the renaming as in the other answer, someting like: `rename (y2 year) (year y2)` and then `sort id year y2`, otherwise all the covariates values in the expanded dataset will be (wrongly) relative to  `y2` and not to `year`. I updated my question to show this.

Comment: I updated my answer to show a more direct approach to ignoring the unwanted values in the dataset being joined to the original.

Answer (score 1):

@William has pointed out the straightforward way.

As an illustration, you can get there with appropriate sorting and auxiliary variables:

```
clear
set more off

*----- example data -----

input ///
id year
1 1992
1 1995
1 1996
2 1992
2 1993
end

list, sepby(id)

*----- what you want -----

bysort id : gen N = _N
expand N

bysort id (year) : gen n = mod(_n-1, N) + 1
bysort id n (year) : gen year2 = year[n]

rename (year2 year) (year year2)

// pretty print
order id year year2
list, sepby(id)
```

Thinking in this way can help when "direct" commands such as `joinby` are not available.

Comment: Thanks @Roberto, I accepted Williams' answer because it's slightly easier to read in my opinion, but I appreciate the use of "auxiliary variables" + bysort as you did.

Comment: You're welcome. I'd use `joinby` myself. The purpose was to illustrate an alternative. Notice the funny-looking line with `mod()` just creates sequences with appropriate ending.

Comment: Yes, I would have never thought you could use `mod()` for the purpose, tricky!