# Stata - Generate unique combinations ignoring order

Tags: stata

I am trying to create a dataset that lists all combinations of rows by ID, but ignores the order of combinations (i.e. Apple -> Orange is the same as Orange -> Apple). I started by using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34246471/data-expansion-so-to-create-all-possible-combinations-of-two-covariates) question, which gets me all combinations, keeping different orders. How can I modify this code for my desired output? Or should I being using a different approach altogether, and what would the approach be?

Code of what I currently do using linked question:

```
clear all

input id str10 fruit 
1 "Apple"
1 "Banana"
1 "Orange"
2 "Orange"
2 "Apple"
3 "Pear"
3 "Kiwi"
3 "Apple"
3 "Lemon"
end

tempfile t1
save `t1'
clear

use `t1'
rename fruit f2
keep id f2
joinby id using `t1'
order id fruit f2
sort id  fruit f2

drop if fruit==f2

list, sepby(id)
```

My desired output is:

```
ID  fruit   f2
1   Apple   Banana
1   Apple   Orange
1   Banana  Orange
2   Orange  Apple
3   Pear    Kiwi
3   Pear    Apple
3   Pear    Lemon
3   Kiwi    Apple
3   Kiwi    Lemon
3   Apple   Lemon
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After `joinby`, you could generate an auxiliary variable which puts fruit and f2 in one variable and sorts them, assuring that the same combinations have the same values. Then you can use `duplicates drop` in terms of this variable and id to drop duplicates.

```
clear 
input id str10 fruit 
1 "Apple"
1 "Banana"
1 "Orange"
2 "Orange"
2 "Apple"
3 "Pear"
3 "Kiwi"
3 "Apple"
3 "Lemon"
end

tempfile t1
save `t1'

rename fruit f2
joinby id using `t1'
order id fruit f2
sort id  fruit f2

drop if fruit==f2
gen combination = cond(fruit < f2, fruit + " " + f2, f2 + " " + fruit)
duplicates drop id combination, force
drop combination

list, sepby(id)

     +----------------------+
     | id    fruit       f2 |
     |----------------------|
  1. |  1    Apple   Banana |
  2. |  1    Apple   Orange |
  3. |  1   Banana   Orange |
     |----------------------|
  4. |  2    Apple   Orange |
     |----------------------|
  5. |  3    Apple     Kiwi |
  6. |  3    Apple    Lemon |
  7. |  3    Apple     Pear |
  8. |  3     Kiwi    Lemon |
  9. |  3     Kiwi     Pear |
 10. |  3    Lemon     Pear |
     +----------------------+
```